# Plugin that checks if player is Original - Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I've tried to make a plugin, that can tell the difference between Original & Warez minecraft player. I've tried many apis but it just simply doesn't work.

Here is my code - https://www.hastebin.com/oyicejaron.java

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Read the [help/on-topic] before posting.

Comment: Set your server to `online-mode=true`.  Then just `return true;`.  Anything else is encouraging bad behavior, breaking several contracts, and generally not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to check wether a certain player name is the name of a premium Minecraft account, I would do the following:

You will have to connect to the Mojang API and make a request evolving the player's name. The mojang API returns no content when there is no player found by that name.
The URL is as follows:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username);
```

where `username` is the username of the player. (in your case `p.getName()`)
Also make sure to surround this statement with a try- and catch block to deal with a possible `MalformedURLException`.

Now we want to check wether the content returned by this page is empty or not. You can read out the content using a `BufferedReader`. You can do that like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

`URL.openStream()`throws an `IOException`. This best to surround this whole block with a try catch block catching an `IOException` since `MalformedURLException` extends `IOException`.

Now to check wether this reader is empty or not, there is not really a method to do so, but I would do that like this

```
boolean empty = reader.lines().count() == 0;
```

this boolean is `true` when the reader is empty and it's `false` when it's not.

Finally, it's important to close this reader, you can do that by typing `reader.close();`